# BucketAdmin Sidebar not working

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am working on the BucketAdmin template by Theme Bucket.

Everything works smooth but when I edit the Side-bar code, it stops collapsing and opening. Here is the original code.

I am a newbie at this so please also explain the issue.

```
<aside>
   <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
      <!-- sidebar menu start-->            
      <div class="leftside-navigation">
         <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
            <li>
               <a href="index.html">
               <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
               <span>Dashboard</span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
               <span>Layouts</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="boxed_page.html">Boxed Page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="horizontal_menu.html">Horizontal Menu</a></li>
                  <li><a href="language_switch.html">Language Switch Bar</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
               <span>UI Elements</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="general.html">General</a></li>
                  <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                  <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                  <li><a href="widget.html">Widget</a></li>
                  <li><a href="slider.html">Slider</a></li>
                  <li><a href="tree_view.html">Tree View</a></li>
                  <li><a href="nestable.html">Nestable</a></li>
                  <li><a href="grids.html">Grids</a></li>
                  <li><a href="calendar.html">Calender</a></li>
                  <li><a href="draggable_portlet.html">Draggable Portlet</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="fontawesome.html">
               <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
               <span>Fontawesome </span>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
               <span>Data Tables</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="basic_table.html">Basic Table</a></li>
                  <li><a href="responsive_table.html">Responsive Table</a></li>
                  <li><a href="dynamic_table.html">Dynamic Table</a></li>
                  <li><a href="editable_table.html">Editable Table</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
               <span>Form Components</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="form_component.html">Form Elements</a></li>
                  <li><a href="advanced_form.html">Advanced Components</a></li>
                  <li><a href="form_wizard.html">Form Wizard</a></li>
                  <li><a href="form_validation.html">Form Validation</a></li>
                  <li><a href="file_upload.html">Muliple File Upload</a></li>
                  <li><a href="dropzone.html">Dropzone</a></li>
                  <li><a href="inline_editor.html">Inline Editor</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
               <span>Mail </span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="mail.html">Inbox</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mail_compose.html">Compose Mail</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mail_view.html">View Mail</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
               <span>Charts</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="morris.html">Morris</a></li>
                  <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chartjs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="flot_chart.html">Flot Charts</a></li>
                  <li><a href="c3_chart.html">C3 Chart</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;">
               <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
               <span>Maps</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li><a href="google_map.html">Google Map</a></li>
                  <li><a href="vector_map.html">Vector Map</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub-menu">
               <a href="javascript:;" class="active">
               <i class="fa fa-glass"></i>
               <span>Extra</span>
               </a>
               <ul class="sub">
                  <li class="active"><a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="lock_screen.html">Lock Screen</a></li>
                  <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                  <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a></li>
                  <li><a href="pricing_table.html">Pricing Table</a></li>
                  <li><ahref="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>
                  <li>
                     <a href="gallery.html">Media Gallery</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="404.html">404 Error</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                  <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
                  <li><a href="blank2.html">Blank2</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="login.html">
               <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
               <span>Login Page</span>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar menu end-->
   </div>
</aside>
<!--sidebar end-->
```

Here is the edited code

```
<aside>
   <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
      <!-- sidebar menu start-->            
      <div class="leftside-navigation">
         <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
            <li> <a href="index.html"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a> </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- sidebar menu end-->
   </div>
</aside>
<!--sidebar end-->
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems the collapsing action works for "sub menus" - can you create a jsfiddle or live demo?

Comment: Yes, tried that on live demo but it still doesnot close. P.S. the the sidebar needs to collapse not the menu.

Comment: Did you edit any javascript files? Do you know how the collapsing is fired in the original code?

Comment: No I didn't edited any files except the basic html to reduce items in my navigation drawer. Sorry for the "don't-know" part I am a newbie in web development.

Comment: @Aziz except for deleting this time I commented the part which I wanted to remove and voila it worked. I don't know what is the difference between deleting and commenting but I would very much like to know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete, I simply commented the part which I wanted to remove and it worked.